# Enable limit in update statement -sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have problem with sqlite, becouse I need to use LIMIT in UPDATE statements.
I have compiled sqlite using this commands:

```
wget http://sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-autoconf-3140100.tar.gz 
tar zxf sqlite-autoconf-3140100.tar.gz 
cd sqlite-autoconf-3140100 
./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static CFLAGS="-g -O2 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT=1"
make
make install
```

when I check if compile option is used result is 1, but when i execute update statement with limit, I got the error

```
sqlite>  select sqlite_compileoption_used('SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT');
1
sqlite> UPDATE table_name SET modified_at = date('now') WHERE id = 11 LIMIT 1;
Error: near "LIMIT": syntax error
```

Am I missing something? I can't find solution.
Every answer is appreciated.

I'm compiling sqlite on docker container FROM php:5.6-apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit) says:

> If this option is defined, then it must also be defined when using the 'lemon' tool to generate a parse.c file. Because of this, this option may only be used when the library is built from source, not from the amalgamation.

So you have to [build your own amalgamation](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html#amal).

Comment: I used wrong sources. When i used Alternative Source Code Formats sqlite compiled corectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me (MacOS):

```bash
STEM=sqlite-src-3410000
FILE=$STEM.zip

if [ -d $STEM ]; then
  echo Folder $STEM exists.
else
  if [ -f $FILE ]; then
    echo File $FILE exists.
  else
    wget https://www.sqlite.org/$(date +'%Y')/$FILE
  fi
  unzip $FILE
fi

cd $STEM && \
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --disable-static --enable-update-limit && \
make sqlite3.c && \
make install && \
echo Done.
```

Verify:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/sqlite3 --version
3.41.0 2023-02-21 18:09:37 05941c2a04037fc3ed2ffae11f5d2260706f89431f463518740f72ada350866d
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone had same problem this way I compiled sqlite

```
wget https://www.sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-src-3140100.zip 
unzip sqlite-src-3140100.zip && cd sqlite-src-3140100 
./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-static CFLAGS="-g -O2 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT=1" 
make sqlite3.c 
make install
```